# SQL Server Special display last row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this database Student.

```
ID ( auto incremment)  Nume       Sum       DataEnter

1                      Alex       100     2013-05-20
2                      Marian     200     2014-04-14
3                      Vasile     150     2012-01-01
4                      Andrei     100     2013-05-04
5                      Teo        200     2013-02-11
```

I use this  to display duplicate :

```
SELECT ID, Nume, Sum, DataEnter, FROM dbo.student
 Where ISNULL(Sum, 0) IN (Select ISNULL (Sum,0) from dbo.student
 group BY SUM
 HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ) 
 order by SUM desc, ID desc, DataEnter desc
```

Display this :

```
200  5  Teo 2013-02-11
200  2  Marian  2014-04-14
100  4  Andrei  2013-05-04
100  1  Alex    2013-05-20
```

Now : I enter a new data for example :

```
100     6      Costy      with today dataenter day : 2014-05-27
```

Display this :

```
200 5   Teo 2013-02-11
200 2   Marian  2014-04-14
100 6   Costy   2014-05-27
100 4   Andrei  2013-05-04
100 1   Alex    2013-05-20
```

I want to display last duplicate category that enter sort by date.  I want to display :

```
100 6   Costy   2014-05-27
100 4   Andrei  2013-05-04
100 1   Alex    2013-05-20
200 5   Teo 2013-02-11
200 2   Marian  2014-04-14
```

because   100   7   Costy   2014-05-27 is the last enter.

Comment: What's your exact question?

Comment: Is it already 2015-05-27? Sh*t.. I'm a year behind.. :)

Comment: Shouldn't you just rearrange the `ORDER BY` then? Something like: `ORDER BY SUM DESC, DataEnter DESC, ID DESC`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
Set Dateformat ymd

Declare @Student table
(ID int identity(1,1),  Name varchar(20),[Sum] int,DataEnter Date)
Insert into @Student Values
('Alex'     ,100,'2013-05-20'),
('Marian'   ,200,'2014-04-14'),
('Vasile'   ,150,'2012-01-01'),
('Andrei'   ,100,'2013-05-04'),
('Teo'      ,200,'2013-02-11')

Select  A.Sum,A.ID,A.Name,A.DataEnter
From    @Student A
Join    (
        Select  Sum [Sum],max(DataEnter) DataEnter
        from    @Student
        group   By Sum 
        having  Count(*) > 1) Lu
On      A.Sum = Lu.Sum
order By Lu.DataEnter Desc,A.ID Desc
```

**Result**

[image]

Adding record

```
Insert into @Student Values
('Costy'     ,100,'2014-05-27')

Select  A.Sum,A.ID,A.Name,A.DataEnter
From    @Student A
Join    (
        Select  Sum [Sum],max(DataEnter) DataEnter
        from    @Student
        group   By Sum 
        having  Count(*) > 1) Lu
On      A.Sum = Lu.Sum
order By Lu.DataEnter Desc,A.ID Desc
```

**Result**

[image]

Adding 1 more record

```
Insert into @Student Values
('Mary'     ,200,'2015-05-27')

Select  A.Sum,A.ID,A.Name,A.DataEnter
From    @Student A
Join    (
        Select  Sum [Sum],max(DataEnter) DataEnter
        from    @Student
        group   By Sum 
        having  Count(*) > 1) Lu
On      A.Sum = Lu.Sum
order By Lu.DataEnter Desc,A.ID Desc
```

**result**.

[image]